# Void Wrappers for Nonvoid Functions With An Argument

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller, mbed

So, I have the following situation:

- I'm coding for the mbed online compliler, on a low-memory microcontroller.
- Real Time performance is very important, I want this to take less than a microsecond. 10 microseconds would be tolerable.
- I'm using their timeout library, which provides an API for calling an ISR after a specified time, but requires that the ISR be a void/void function. (including a member function.

  ```
  void TimeoutCallback(void) { do stuff that I want to do on timeout.} // ISR

  Timeout to; 
  to.attach_us(&TimeoutCallback, 750) // Call TimeoutCallback in 750 us.
  ```
- I created a vector of Timeout objects, which all get set at once, to the same function, with a different amount of time. I want to somehow pass into the TimeoutCallback *which* Timeout object called it.

My initial thought was to overload the Timeout class to allow it to accept int function(int) function pointers, and to accept a number in the overloaded attach function that gets passed to said function pointer. However, I'm unsure whether this is actually practical given the messy (and device-specific) inheritance of the Timeout class.

Now, I wonder whether there is a way to programatically create a void/void function that wraps a void/int function, and included a changeable reference int which is passed to the wrapped function.

Comment: Globals on what? I don't quite get it? I can see how I could pass some information around, but still need a way to *identify* the functions.

Comment: "I want this to take less than a microsecond" is almost certainly not compatible with most C++ specific features such as the standard library. Btw is `void TimeoutCallback(void)` the actual ISR or a function called from the ISR? Because the true ISR would have to be declared as static and can obviously take no parameters.

Comment: @Lundin: An ISR declared `static`? How would that be linked into the interrupt table (which most likely resides in the startup module)?

Comment: @Olaf Well from what I can tell here, this function is part of a class, in which case it has to be static. But I guess this function is likely not the actual ISR. As for how interrupt tables are defined, it varies a lot. Most common seems to be to specify them in some linker file rather than to implement them in C code (as an array of integers or function pointers).

Comment: @Lundin: CMSIS uses a standard array of function pointers for Cortex-M in the startup module. For gcc/ELF, it uses weak default handlers. But I'm not sure about mbed (isn't that freescales stuff for their controller platforms (ColdFire, Kinetis)?

Comment: No, it's the mbed API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your library can call member functions, you can create an adapter ala...

```
template <typename Func, Func func>
struct Adapter
{
    Adapter(int n) : n_(n) { }

    void f() { func(n_); }
    int n_;
};
```

To use it:

```
Adapter<void(*)(int), My_Function_Expecting_An_Int> adapter(the_int);
to.attach_us(&adapter, &decltype(adapter)::f, timeout_us);
```

Make sure the `adapter`'s lifetime lasts until the callback....

---

To call a member function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MyObj
{
    void f(int n) { std::cout <<"hi " << n << "\n"; }
};

template <typename Class, typename PFunc>
struct Adapter
{
    Adapter(Class& object, PFunc pFunc, int n) : object_(object), pFunc_(pFunc), n_(n) { }

    void f() { (object_.*pFunc_)(n_); }

    Class& object_;
    PFunc pFunc_;
    int n_;
};

int main()
{
    MyObj myObj;

    Adapter<MyObj, void(MyObj::*)(int)> adapter(myObj, &MyObj::f, 43);
    adapter.f();
}
```

Comment: @ikrase: yes - a keyword; both `typename` and `class` can be used to introduce template parameters for which a type is expected at instantiation: there's no functional difference.

Comment: @ikrase: I noticed two mistakes in my template - sorry!  Fix posted.  You can see the code working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6e68673a9d476ee).

Comment: Looks good, though could you explain the differences between what's above and what you posted on coliru?

Comment: @ikrase: the `struct Adapter` code on coliru is identical to that above, and the code in main illustrates how it's able to create a `void ()` member function that can be called a la `adapter.f()`, that in turn calls the non-member `void f(int)` function with the value specified to the adapter constructor.  That's all just for illustration/testing.  For actual use in mbed, you would use the `to.attach_us` code above.

Comment: Yeah, I actually confused some tabs. Sorry.

Comment: OK.... actually... one more question? Is it appropriate for the function_expecting_an_int to be a class member function (member of the class that all this is working in in my setup) or should it just be a function? 

Thank you a huge amount for what you've done for me already. You're the best.

Comment: @ikrase: if you'd like `function_expecting_an_int` to be a member function, you'll need to give the adapter an object instance against which to invoke it: I've added code above (also available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/899352754b00356f)).  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

While Tony D's solution is appropriate if using the mbed `Ticker` class, there is an alternative method using the mbed [`RtosTimer`](https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/RTOS#rtos-timer).

The `RtosTimer` constructor takes a `void*` argument that is passed to the handler on timeout.  The handler has the signature:

```
void handler(void const* n)
```

Where `n` is the pointer argument passed to the constructor and can be used to ID the specific timeout.

Unlike `Ticker` where the timeout function runs in the interrupt context, for `RtosTimer` the handler runs as a thread, so gives greater flexibility, but potentially greater latency.

Comment: In general this would be good but IIRC the rtos uses milliseconds, so not enough resolution.

Comment: @ikrase : Agreed; it is not useful for very high resolution timing.  You can no doubt change the underlying RTOS tick, but that would affect the whole system and is not a particularly efficient solution if only one task requires such resolution.

Comment: @Clifford: good find! Being able to pass a `void*` in is the traditional way for an API to support passing arbitrary information - e.g. [`pthread_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)'s final argument.  While `sizeof(void*)` is probably always `>= sizeof(int)`, ensuring you can pass and recover arbitrary `int`s, it's also useful for passing pointers to `struct`s or arrays with `> sizeof(void*)` data, should that be needed.